# How to get the exact action that is done in a table, including the column name modified

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I have a database with around 15 tables inside it. Now, I have created a trigger below which will save logs into a secondary audit table. I will create triggers for all my tables, because I want to monitor all the actions performed by users inside my database. Please help me with my code below, correct me if I'm doing it wrong. I'm also seeking help on how to record the specific event that happened in a table. For example a user modified the salary of a certain employee, the log should look like: Action_done --- update salary. I don't need to know who's the exact employee is, just what has been done on what column. Lastly, I used a sequence to autopopulate the log id of my audit table, Am I doing it right? Thank you in advance!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER database_level_audit
after insert or delete or update on employee
for each row 
WHEN (new.eventlog_id IS NULL) 
declare 
v_user varchar2;
v_date date;
v_time timestamp;
act_done varchar2(20) := case when updating then 'Update' when deleting then 'Delete' else 'Insert' end;
begin
select user, To_Char(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYY'), To_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'HH12:MI:SS')  into v_user, v_date, v_time from dual;
SELECT eventlog_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.eventlog_id FROM dual;
if inserting then
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (:NEW.eventlog_id, v_user, v_date, v_time, act_done , 'customer');
elsif deleting then
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (:NEW.eventlog_id, v_user, v_date, v_time, act_done,'customer');
elsif updating then
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (:NEW.eventlog_id, v_user, v_date, v_time, act_done ,'customer');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: If it were me, I would use flashback technology rather than triggers.

Have a look at that page to make an opinion for yourself.
https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/a-fresh-look-at-auditing-row-changes

Comment: Upon compiling, I got this error: ORA-00904: "EVENTLOG_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Apparently, there's no EVENTLOG_ID column in a table you think it is.

Comment: Actually, there is: EVENTLOG_ID NUMBER(3,0) No  1

Comment: Can someone please tell me if im doing it right?